# Pyvista plotting 3D numpy array, always blank

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pyvista

I am trying to plot a 3D numpy array (256 x 256 x 256) as essentially an array of points, which should be colored by their value. I keep getting something like this
[image]

if I multiply by data by 1000, I get this:
[image]

My data is a 3D np array composed of slices, and the slices look like this:
[image]

There are about 50 or so slices, so the 3D visualization should be showing a sphere. I can visualize the slices just fine

My code is a modified example of this example: https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/02-plot/volume.html using the technique given here in this link to make a pyvista.UniformGrid object out of a 3D numpy array: https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/00-load/create-uniform-grid.html

```
def plot_3d_pyvista(self):
    import pyvista as pv
    values = self.reconstructed_source_3D


    # Create the spatial reference
    grid = pv.UniformGrid()
    

    # Set the grid dimensions: shape because we want to inject our values on the
    #   POINT data
    grid.dimensions = values.shape
    
    # Edit the spatial reference
    #grid.origin = (1, 1, 1)  # The bottom left corner of the data set
    #grid.spacing = (1, 1, 1)  # These are the cell sizes along each axis
    
    # Add the data values to the cell data
    grid.point_data["values"] = values.flatten(order="F")
    
    p = pv.Plotter()
    p.add_volume(grid)

    p.show()
```

If I use a sphere, eg, a 3D numpy array of zeros with only the center spherical elements set to 1, I get something like this which clearly shows a sphere but is way too transparent: [image]

Alternatively, if anyone knows a way using a different package to plot a volume like this, I could use that. I just need a way to visualize what the 3D looks like.

Comment: Hi, did you eventualy solve the issue? I am facing the same situation now, having been left with either empty or completely full grid.

Comment: @Vojtooo yes I did solve it. You have to normalize the values to around 0 - 255 for it to show up properly using this PyVista.